# The 'subscribe' property does not exist in the 'OperatorFunction<{}, {}>' type

Tags: typescript, angular6, subscribe

This a service file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import {map, catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from "../../node_modules/rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SessionService {
  BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000"
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  handleError(e) {
  return Observable.throw(e.json().message);
}

signup(formSignup) {
  return this.http.post(`${this.BASE_URL}/api/signup`, formSignup)
  .pipe(map(res => res.json())),
  catchError(this.handleError);
}
```

Here is where the subscribe method showing this error

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SessionService } from '../../services/session.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup-form',
  templateUrl: './signup-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup-form.component.css']
})
export class SignupFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
  private sessionService:SessionService, 
  private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sendSignupForm(myForm){
    this.sessionService.signup(myForm.value)
      .subscribe(()=> this.router.navigate(['private']))
    }
   }
```

I have a service file where I have to call my api to get the api and when I subscribe to the method, it gives me this error:

> The `subscribe' property does not exist in the`OperatorFunction<{},
>   {}>>' type

I don't understand why you're giving me this mistake, I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: When I subscribe to my service, I get the error: " The 'subscribe' property does not exist in the 'OperatorFunction<{}, {}>' type ", and I don't understand why

Comment: What does this return `signup(myForm.value)`?

Comment: The values of my signup form. I just edited the question, adding the service

Answer (score 0):

There may be a couple of things wrong with your `signup` function. In Angular 6, the `map(res => res.json())` portion of your service is no longer needed. Also I think you may have mis-copied/pasted because that function has some syntax errors (missing parenthesis or `.` operator?)

```
signup(formSignup) {
  return this.http.post(`${this.BASE_URL}/api/signup`, formSignup)
                  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```